# How to get the data from the android service?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-service

I Create a GPSservice for my app and I would like to get the data obtained from the GPSservice for my another list activity and show it. The problem is that it cannot be shown in the list.

the splash code to start the GPSservice:

```
public class splash extends Activity
{   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startService(new Intent("com.example.geotask.gpsservice"));
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                    splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                    splash.this.finish();
            }
        }, 1000);
     }
```

The GPSservice code:

```
public class GPSservice extends Service
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public  ArrayList<String> position = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    public  ArrayList<Long> time=new ArrayList<Long>();
    public  ArrayList<Integer> lat= new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    public  ArrayList<Integer> lon= new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();


}
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startID)
{LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
String provider = locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10, locationListener);
}
private void additem(Location location){
     String latLongString = "Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + "\nLong:" + location.getLongitude();
     position.add(latLongString);
     long t=location.getTime();
     time.add(t);

}

private void addgeo(Location location){
    int x=(int)location.getLatitude()*1000000;
    int y=(int)location.getLongitude()*1000000;
    lat.add(x);
    lon.add(y);


}


LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            additem(location);
                    addgeo(location);
            Intent intent= new Intent("com.example.geotask.gpsdata");
            intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("lat", (ArrayList<Integer>) lat);
            intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("lon", (ArrayList<Integer>) lon);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", (ArrayList<String>) position);
            sendBroadcast(intent);    }



        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){


        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
      };
}
```

The list activity code:

```
public class list extends Activity{ 
    ArrayList details = new ArrayList();
    private BroadcastReceiver gpsreceiver;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter("com.example.geotask.gpsdata");
        intentFilter.addAction("com.example.geotask.gpsdata");
        gpsreceiver=new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override 
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                List<String> ex=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("data");
                int i=0;
                for(i=0; i<ex.size(); i++)
                {
                    listdetails Detail = new listdetails();
                    Detail.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    Detail.setPlace(ex.get(i));
                    Detail.setTime("2012.12.2");
                    details.add(Detail);
            }
            }
        };
        this.registerReceiver(gpsreceiver, intentFilter);


        setContentView(R.layout.list); 
        ListView listView; 
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        customlist Adapter = new customlist(details, this);
        listView.setAdapter(Adapter);


    }
```

Comment: use a handler and messenger, there's no reason why you need the inner class in the first piece of code to do a postdelayed and send an intent.

Comment: could u plz explain clearly for me, I am a freshman for android programming.thx:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your receiver

```
registerReceiver(gpsreceiver, intentFilter);
```

Remember to unregister onDestroy.

Comment: can i do it in the manifest.xml? Cuz I didn't create a new class extending BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: you can declare a broadcast receiver in the manifest, but in that case you would need to create a new class extending BroadcastReceiver.  If you want to tie the receiver to your activity lifecycle you should use registerReceiver, not the manifest.

Comment: Thx for your info. I modified the code and added the registerReceiver(), but the problems is still there. The list still shows nothing.

Comment: Err, you might want to register the receiver after you have created it.  Move registerReceiver() to the line above setContentView()

Comment: You also need to update the adapter with the new details when you receive the broadcast.  I'd suggest you also make use of android.util.Log so you can see whether a broadcast is being sent / arrives